# Java ANT to combine tasks

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I am trying to write a task that will combine all the tasks in by build.xml

```
<project name="HW4_Build">

<target name="mkedir">
    <mkdir dir="bld/class/cscie55/hw4"/>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bld"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean, mkedir">
    <javac destdir="bld/class" srcdir="src/cscie55/hw4"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="HW4.jar" basedir="bld/class"/>
</target>

</project>
```

Is following method right way to go about this?

```
<ant antfile="build"/>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't the jar target doing exactly that? The dependency chain of that target seems to touch all other targets. compile->clean->mkdir. If you want you can add a default attribute at the project level.

Answer (score 1):

In this build.xml you might just want to try:

```
<project name="HW4_Build" default="jar">
```

Because the jar target already includes the other targets via the dependency chain.

```
<ant antfile="build"/>
```

Is used for invoking another build file. Not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<antcall target="target"/>
```

Use this to define a target that combines all your other targets.

Although this won't exactly work in your case since you are using `depends`... So you only need to call your last target in the dependency chain.